# Passing pointer to a function with parameters as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I have code, where I need to implement passing pointer to a function with an argument, like in code below, but it doen't seems to be possible.

```
bool StudentAbsenceTableApp::loadFile(const QString &fileName)
{
    fw.moveToThread(this->thread());
    fw.setParent(this);
    //I need: &(StudentAbsenceTableApp::experimentFunction(fileName)
    QFuture<bool> future =  QtConcurrent::run(this, &StudentAbsenceTableApp::experimentFunction);
    fw.setFuture(future);

    progressBar->show();
}
// I need: experimentFunction(const QString& fileName)
bool StudentAbsenceTableApp::experimentFunction()
{
    QString fileName = "/media/bsuir/data.xml";
    XMLParser *xmlParser = new XMLParser(model);

    xmlParser->read(fileName);
    setCurrentFileName(fileName);
    statusBar()->showMessage(tr("Файл загружен"), 2000);
    documentModified = false;

    return true;
}
```

But there are no ways, I could find.

Comment: have you tried using a simple `signal and slot` based call?

Comment: If you are able to modify the definition of the class, you can modify the declaration of the member function `expermientFunction()`. If you are not able to modify the class definition, then you are right. You are out of luck there.

Comment: Just simply `QtConcurrent::run(this, &StudentAbsenceTableApp::experimentFunction, fileName)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtConcurrent::run Supports passing arguments to the function.

```
QFuture<bool> future =  QtConcurrent::run(this, &StudentAbsenceTableApp::experimentFunction, fileName);
```

Refer the documentation : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#passing-arguments-to-the-function